# Remote debugging in Visual Studio 2015 can't connect to my app:(

Tags: visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I'm able to connect to remote machine (Windows Server 2012) and can attach to various processes both managed and unmanaged, but unfortunately - not to my app!!

I get:

'Unable to attach to the process. Visual Studio debugger cannot connect to remote computer.Unable to initiate DCOM communication. Please see Help ...'

I would like to note that:

1. My app is Windows x64 .NET WPF C# application build in debug mode with
   pdb files in  place and all debug symbols/info attached etc. I can
   attach debuger to the same binary running locally.
2. Both remote debugger tools and Visual Studio Community are Update
   3.
3. I can connect to other managed/unmanaged processes on remote machine, I can
   pause/start/stop them etc
4. System logs in Event Viewer on both machines (mine is Windows 10)
   don't give  much info - this error seems related but nor timings do
   not perfectly match, not Google doesn't give some clues

   > Unable to start a DCOM Server: App.AppXhyg4cy62s7gghctkf48aq5csrzdn44mk.mca as    Unavailable/Unavailable. The error:
   >   "3236560897"
   >   Happened while starting this command:
   >   "C:\WINDOWS\system32\backgroundTaskHost.exe" -ServerName:App.AppX9c2je2s29fsgzvc6339srtj1ypxtqfe5.mca

**Update**:

> Unable to start a DCOM Server:
>   App.AppXhyg4cy62s7gghctkf48aq5csrzdn44mk.mca as
>   Unavailable/Unavailable. The error: "3236560897" ...

clearly is connected to the issue, this is in event viewer from my local windows 10 machine.

**Update 2**:

I attached alert to that error event in the system log on my local machine, and well - seems it's **not connected** to the issue, as occasionally when I don't try to attach to the process and don't touch debugger at all, the error appears and event fires and the alert popups(( though when I try actively - I get like 3-5 popups per hour, and when don't touch remote debugger - like 1-2 per 5-6 hours. This may sound confusing, but maybe it will be somehow helpful as extra info as I would like to remind, that error in Visual Studio debugger says 'Unable to initiate DCOM communication..'

Comment: Hmya, so you have a wonky Windows Store app installed on your machine that is generating IBackgroundTask errors.  Nothing to do with remote debugging or a WPF app.  The kind of rock you have to turn over is the kind that blocks a network connection, preventing the remote debugger from talking to the machine.  Anti-malware and firewalls are always on the top of that list, especially so when you made an EXE appear from seemingly nowhere.  Disable that kind of stuff and try again.

Comment: Hi, thanx, I disabled all the soft right from the start - Windows Firewall and antivirus:(.. Yes, it looks like it can't connect back to local machine from remote one.